# How to put a value into a TextBox in a GridVIew?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How do I put the value from a query into TextBox, TbHoursCompleted, when "Yes" is selected in RadioButtonList, RbCompleted?

I'm sure that nothing about what I've tried so far is correct.  I don't even know how to reference the TextBox to put a value into it.

Thanks for any help.

.aspx:

```
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Save" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainingID" HeaderText="Training ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TrainingID" Visible="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AttendeeID" HeaderText="Attendee ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AttendeeID" Visible="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Attendee Name" SortExpression="DisplayName" ItemStyle-CssClass="colPad" Visible="True" ReadOnly="True" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Completed" SortExpression="Completed" ControlStyle-CssClass="colPad">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="RbCompleted_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Completed") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle CssClass="colPad"></ControlStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hours Completed" SortExpression="HoursCompleted">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbHoursCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HoursCompleted", "{0:n2}") %>' onkeypress="return num(this);" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LbHoursCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HoursCompleted", "{0:n2}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Width="40px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StaffRosterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sql = "SELECT Hours FROM Training WHERE TrainingID = @TrainingID";
        SqlCommand DBCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, DBConn);

        try
        {
            DBConn.Open();
            DBCmd.Parameters.Add("@TrainingID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("TrainingID");   //GridView1.TrainingID Selected Row column Index 1;  ?    //EmployeeName.Text;

            SqlDataReader dr = DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var tHours = dr["Hours"].ToString();
                    TextBox t = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbHoursCompleted");
                    t.Text = tHours.ToString();
                }

                dr.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //msgFetch.Text = "No records found.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        DBCmd.Dispose();
        DBConn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the textbox value dynamically when the user changes the radio button selection? Or just check if the value coming back from your bind data is already "yes"? Perhaps both? I assume your query also stores this radiobutton RbCompleted value.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update the Textbox value when the user changes the radio button selection.  And yes, I want to store the selected value of RbCompleted.

Comment: The value that I want to put into the TextBox is in another table.  The GridView is coming from "Attendees."  The HoursCompleted is in the 'Hours' column of the "Training" table.
So, when "Yes" is selected in Completed, the number of hours completed can be gotten from the Training table and saved into the Attendees table indicating the number of hours completed.

I'm thinking I may change the way I'm trying to do this.  Maybe, in the RadioButton SelectedIndexChanged, put an UPDATE Attendees.HoursCompleted FROM Training.Hours?

Comment: See my 2 examples below. I thus show how a sql join is not only better, but in most cases less code and work. Do note the "tip" about using the data row view to get the full data row during binding - even rows and values NOT dropped into the GV.

Comment: I would agree with @AlbertD.Kallal that staying away from rowdatabound is highly preferable for performance reasons. I would focus on writing a good SQL query with a sqldatasource that meets all the gridview's needs, which will require joins in this case. Then use RbCompleted_SelectedIndexChanged to handle when the radio button is changed.  Rowdatabound or asp.net booleans can be used to read the value of the radiobutton and perform the data added to your textbox, perhaps with hidden column data.

Comment: See my trick used. We don't even need a hidden column. I often just cook up and add a attribute to the given control - so, just add the required value from the SQL left join to the radiobutton, and we have use of that value - see my 2nd code edit below with screen cap gif - you can see the code again is/was reduced, and again all due to using sql to do all the dirty work for us.

Answer (score 0):

How this can work:

We supply, bind the GV with the data.

On row data bind, we "could" pull the other data, but do we want or need to?

Let's take this simple example. Some people, and they have a hotel id.

So, this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="40%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="From City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Hotel_ID" HeaderText="Hotel" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And our code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        LoadGrid();
}

void LoadGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM People";

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Now, of course we want the hotel name from table Hotels.

We COULD perhaps execute a WHOLE new query for each row in the data row bind event, but that is really beating the SQL server to death, since for each row, we will have to execute a whole new Query.

So, in 99% of cases, we should pull in that extra column using SQL.

The SQL required is simple, and rather easy.

We will left join (since some people still are to show, but may not have that hotel ID set).

So, to our markup, we will add the HotelName, say like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel" />
```

So, now the SQL becomes this:

```
 string strSQL =
   @"SELECT *, HotelName FROM People
   LEFT JOIN HotelsA on HotelsA.ID = People.Hotel_ID";
```

And now the grid shows this:

[image]

(we of course could/would/should remove the hotel_id column from above).

So, really in the vast number of cases, to pull that related value from the other table? Well, we use a "join" to get/lookup/enjoy use of any additional columns from that other table.

If we are to use row data bound event, then for 25 rows, we would have to execute 25 separate SQL queries - we really don't want to do that unless we exhausted all other simple approaches, and in most cases that simple approach will also have the best performance, and even better, wind up requiring less code on our part.

Now, let's assume we do have a RB (radio button list) in the GV, and we are to ONLY show that other value if the Rb is set = yes.

Ok, so our markup then becomes this:

```
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbCompleted" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("ShowHotel") %>' >
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server"
                            Text="" >
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Now, the row data bound event is this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            Debug.Print(gData["ShowHotel"].ToString());
            if (gData["ShowHotel"].ToString() == "Yes")
            {
                Label lblHotel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("txtHotel");
                lblHotel.Text = gData["HotelName"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note VERY close in above. The data row values I am using and operating on is NOT the grid row, but the "data row view". This gives me the full row of data used for binding, and thus EVEN values from the table that are NOT displayed in the GV are still available. The data row view goes out of scope AFTER binding is complete, but during binding, we have full use of the data source.

So, once again, we really don't need to execute a query for each row, and your criteria to "join" Hours on/by training ID can still be done with that SQL that supplies the GV.

As noted, you could create/execute/have/build/code out the SQL and query for each row of the GV data bind, but once again, as above shows, you far better off to join in that value in the base query - EVEN if you not going to use/display for all rows. And note how we could join in multiple columns from that 2nd table, and note again that such columns do NOT have to be placed in the GV, but can be used from the data row view source. (so, for tax calc, or even color formatting based on some other status column, we can use/see that column, even when not in a GV control, but existing in the data source.

So, the result for above is now this:

[image]

I had a test column called "ShowHotel" to drive the RB button, but as noted, the concept should 100% apply to your example.

## Edit: Change gv on change of Radio button choice

OK, so once again, having that data column joined in becomes VERY handy.

So Radiobutton list markup becomes this - auto post back

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbCompleted" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Eval("ShowHotel") %>' 
        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RbCompleted_SelectedIndexChanged"
        MyHotelName = '<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' >
        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And code behind becomes this:

```
    protected void RbCompleted_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList RB = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)RB.NamingContainer;

        Label txtHotel = (Label)gRow.FindControl("txtHotel");
        if (RB.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes")
            txtHotel.Text = RB.Attributes["MyHotelName"];
        else
            txtHotel.Text = "";            
    }
```

So, now we get/see this:

[image]

Comment: Very thorough response. I would add that he needs to do an update to his gridview row in his "RbCompleted_SelectedIndexChanged" event when the user changes the radio button list to yes.

Comment: Very good point - see my edit, and as to how simple that code becomes. This is is "all due" to making good design choices in the first place. So, since I always pull in that value, then note how trivial the RB button choice change works - see the screen/gif to see the code in action.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rory and Albert.  Sorry for my late response, I had a long weekend and we had an all staff meeting today.
You are quite correct; I do not want to query the database on every row.  The Join method is exactly what I want to do.
Actually accessing the TextBox in the GridView was something I had no idea how to do.   I wasn't even able to figure out a way to just stick a test value into that TextBox upon RbCompleted selected index changed.
Is it okay if I ask you any additional questions, if I run into trouble implementing or understanding your examples?

Comment: Well, we could pull the one data row, and sometimes we have not much choice in the matter - but, "so far" in this example, we don't need that one database record pull to get that other value. As for follow up questions? Always best to start a new question, but you can also try in the comments here if the question is expanding or limited to the current example.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.  I just meant questions for clarification or such as, "where do I put specified code", not a completely new question.